# How to set a classpath via GroovyShell?

Tags: groovy, classpath

Following disk setup

```
temp/
  Folder/
    myPackage/
        Person.groovy
  test.groovy
  script.groovy
```

'script.groovy' file content

```
import myPackage.Person

new Person()
```

'test.groovy' file content

```
def cl = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().classLoader)
cl.addURL (new URL ('file://C:/temp/Folder'))

new GroovyShell(cl).evaluate (new File ('C:/temp/script.groovy'))
```

Issue:

"groovy c:\temp\test.groovy" results in

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup 
failed:
C:\temp\script.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class myPackage.Person
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import myPackage.Person
   ^

1 error
```

But 'groovy -cp C:\temp\Folder c:\temp\test.groovy' works of course.

Where is my logical fault? Shouldn't load the prepared class loader the class Person from the added class path?

Regards,
Gert

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering similar issues with trying to execute Groovy files via Jenkins.

```
09:00:45 ERROR: startup failed:
09:00:45 automation_foodoo.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class com.foo.fooclass
09:00:45  @ line 11, column 1.
09:00:45    import com.foo.fooclass
09:00:45    ^
09:00:45 
09:00:45 1 error
09:00:45 
09:00:48 Finished: FAILURE
```

**Actions taken with NO positive results:**

- Setting the CLASSPATH in the .bash_profile

  ```
  CLASSPATH=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/JobName/src/main/groovy
  export CLASSPATH
  ```
- Setting the classpath in Jenkins itself via the "Inject environment variables..." setting by setting the property content

  ```
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/JobName/src/main/groovy
  ```
- Running ANY Groovy file via Groovy cli that has ANY 'import' statement will return the same 'unable to resolve class'

Just as you mentioned in your original post, when I run the Groovy file by including the '-cp' setting in the cli, it works fine.

I am adding myself to this post with my info to hopefully rekindle the fire on this post and find someone out there that has figured this out :)

Comment: Ever found a solution to importing into jenkins pipeline? It's just ridiculous to me that it's so diffucult a simple, personal java class